# use a smartphone mic with a mixer

Tags: microphone

I need an app that makes the output jack audio of the smartphone coincides with what is picking up the microphone. In other words, I would like to use the microphone of the smartphone, like a normal microphone to be connected to a mixer. from an electrical point of view it is feasible, I was wondering if it was possible even on the software side.

has a similar app already been created?

Comment: Yeah you can do this using a Bluetooth voice changer for example.

Comment: I would like to use a very common aux cable. the question is about the software side

Comment: Yes it's possible, depending on your headphone jack... It might be a Four pin jack with microphone pin... So a normal auxiliary won't work as it has 3 pin ( Ground, Right & Left speakers )

Comment: @zillinium I thank you for the information you are sharing. however the thing that matters to me is if there is software that directs what the microphone captures towards the audio jack output.

Comment: Yes, most of them are designed around being a Voice Changer.... It's just a little annoying to use with AUX cords

Comment: @zillinium I ask you directly: I look for an app that "hijacks" towards the headphone output, what is listening on the microphone. a realtime voice changer app, it might be fine, but I'd like my original voice.

Comment: It's rather easy to build, however It needs headphones to test the app or else it has feedback into the microphone... I understand that you specifically are not using the devices speakers... however the feedback issue usually stops the development of such apps... You can use a voice changer with no effect added to produce the realtime pass through ... I can build you one for testing purposes.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

> here's a built one that I'm talking about....

### Direct Download APK from my Google Drive

### [New Mic2Aux.apk](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=12_KCkaHg_uViaS2L51y4eKz07l5XAjPh&export=download)

- This version has control over the 3 pin - 4 Pin microphone, using audio source changing in settings.

Hope this helps clarify how it works.

- The microphone is recorded into a stream
- The stream is played via the headset or main speaker
- When using No headset, the Audio is looping from speaker to microphone continually getting louder.
- If using Aux cord, there's a delay between processing into a stream and then playing via the output.
- It does work as an example app on my device, however not efficient enough for realtime recording.

[image: changes, themes]
[image: homepage]